# Horizontal bar to enlarge textarea

Tags: questions, user-interface, support

How does the bar work, with which I can enlarge the input text area?

I'd like to know where I can find it in JavaScript (what .js defines the functions, etc), if that's possible.

Thanks

Comment: Probably more suited for SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly how SO does it, but there are a number of jQuery plugins to accomplish the effect; one is [TextArea Resizer](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/TextAreaResizer)

Comment: Indeed, SO uses TestArea Resizer. Thanks.